# Custom UI in Blazor Authentication Project

Tags: blazor

I created a server side Blazor project (dotnet core 3.1) and used Single User for authentication mode.
There is much code in the created sample project.

My goal is to have my own UI Elements (Login Username + Password) but project relies on:
Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity.UI where I Can't change the UI for Login etc.

Is there a simple way to call the Login & Register functionality in custom code?

Thx!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the scaffolding system to add, as for instance, the Login file to your project, and then alter the UI as you find fit.

Do the following:

1. Right click on the Identity folder --> Add --> New Scaffolded Item...
2. In the Add New Scaffolded Item dialog select Common -- > Identity, and then click the Add button.
3. In the Add Identity window Check Account/Login, select the Data Context Class in the list box. Click on the + sign on the right to select and update the name, then press Add.
4. Click the Add button at the bottom of the window to end the procedure.
5. This creates the pair Login.cshtml.cs and Login.cshtml in the Account folder.
6. Edit the files according to your whim. You can Add UI elements, add additional functionality, etc.

Comment: Thank you @enet! The only problem is how to merge the cshtml files with a razor file. Because the cshtml has big hidden structure in background that the razor file doesn't have... is there any tutorial or tip regarding this? Thanks!

Comment: @baer999, yes, you've created a new question, didn't you ?;) And I've posted my answer, didn't you see ? It's here, man: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59849119/merge-scaffolded-login-page-into-razor-page

Comment: This is not an answer. Blazor uses a different authentication system than Razor pages. You can't re-use the Razor implementation. This is how it works with Blazor. I'm still searching for a sample implementation of it. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/security/?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#authenticationstateprovider-service

Answer (score 1):

look at my example https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=vb-net-com.CallMicroservicesFromBlazorWithJwtProtection
in this case I'm not only created custom AU in Blazor, but moreover, for calling microservices I change AU from ASP.NET.CORE cookie to JWT authentication.

Comment: Thank you, this was very helpful. I keep stumbling over the amount of magic .NET has and the documentation is making it worse, by showing even more magic in default cases, with only vague explanations as to how to change the defaults to something useful