# Merge scaffolded Login page into Razor page

Tags: blazor

I work with Blazor and dotnet core 3.1.1 created a sample Server Side application and scaffolded a login and register page (Identity Scaffold).

Problem is now that I want to merge the functionality of the cshtml files into the given razor files.

Exactly: I want to take the functionality of Step 1 (see screenshot) into the Counter.razor file (Step 2).

[image: Project explorer]

problem is that the cshtml takes properties, classes and files into account that are not known in my razor 
file.

e.g.:

- 
- public async Task OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
- public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
- Login.cshtml.cs inherits from PageModel

All this and more makes me fail the integration of the given authorization mechanism.

Does anyone have a hint, a link to a turorial or something that helps me on my journey?

Thanks a lot!

```
   [AllowAnonymous]
public class LoginModel : PageModel
{
    private readonly UserManager<BlazorApp5User> _userManager;
    private readonly SignInManager<BlazorApp5User> _signInManager;
    private readonly ILogger<LoginModel> _logger;

    public LoginModel(SignInManager<BlazorApp5User> signInManager, 
        ILogger<LoginModel> logger,
        UserManager<BlazorApp5User> userManager)
    {
        _userManager = userManager;
        _signInManager = signInManager;
        _logger = logger;
    }

    [BindProperty]
    public InputModel Input { get; set; }

    public IList<AuthenticationScheme> ExternalLogins { get; set; }

    public string ReturnUrl { get; set; }

    [TempData]
    public string ErrorMessage { get; set; }

    public class InputModel
    {
        [Required]
        [EmailAddress]
        public string Email { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [DataType(DataType.Password)]
        public string Password { get; set; }

        [Display(Name = "Remember me?")]
        public bool RememberMe { get; set; }
    }

    public async Task OnGetAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(ErrorMessage))
        {
            ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, ErrorMessage);
        }

        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        // Clear the existing external cookie to ensure a clean login process
        await HttpContext.SignOutAsync(IdentityConstants.ExternalScheme);

        ExternalLogins = (await _signInManager.GetExternalAuthenticationSchemesAsync()).ToList();

        ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
    }

    public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync(string returnUrl = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            // This doesn't count login failures towards account lockout
            // To enable password failures to trigger account lockout, set lockoutOnFailure: true
            var result = await _signInManager.PasswordSignInAsync(Input.Email, Input.Password, Input.RememberMe, lockoutOnFailure: false);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                _logger.LogInformation("User logged in.");
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            if (result.RequiresTwoFactor)
            {
                return RedirectToPage("./LoginWith2fa", new { ReturnUrl = returnUrl, RememberMe = Input.RememberMe });
            }
            if (result.IsLockedOut)
            {
                _logger.LogWarning("User account locked out.");
                return RedirectToPage("./Lockout");
            }
            else
            {
                ModelState.AddModelError(string.Empty, "Invalid login attempt.");
                return Page();
            }
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return Page();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@baer999, This is how you can call the Login page from Blazor to authenticate a user. It also provides the code to create Login button, Logout button, etc.

Do the following:

1. Create in the Pages folder a component named RedirectToLogin that redirects the user to the Login view with the following code:

### RedirectToLogin.razor

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager

@code{
  [Parameter]
  public string ReturnUrl {get; set;}
  protected override  void OnInitialized()
  {
        ReturnUrl = "~/" + ReturnUrl;
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"Identity/Account/Login?returnUrl= 
       {ReturnUrl}", forceLoad:true);
  }
}
```

- Add the Authorize attribute to the pages you want to authorize, as for instance, the Counter or FetchData components:

  @attribute [Authorize]

Add the attribute at the top of the components.

Replace the following code with the code in the App component:

### App.razor

```
    <CascadingAuthenticationState>
    <Router AppAssembly="@typeof(Program).Assembly">
    <Found Context="routeData">
            <AuthorizeRouteView RouteData="@routeData" 
                     DefaultLayout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <NotAuthorized>
                   @{
                     var returnUrl = 
                NavigationManager.ToBaseRelativePath(NavigationManager.Uri);
                <RedirectToLogin ReturnUrl="@returnUrl"/>

                }
                </NotAuthorized>
                <Authorizing>
                    Wait...
                </Authorizing>
            </AuthorizeRouteView>
     </Found>
    <NotFound>
            <LayoutView Layout="@typeof(MainLayout)">
                <p>Sorry, there's nothing at this address.</p>
            </LayoutView>
    </NotFound>
 </Router>
</CascadingAuthenticationState>
```

Also inject the NavigationManager at the top of the App component like this:

```
@inject NavigationManager NavigationManager
```

To test this, at the top of the Fetchdata (or Counter if you like) component page add the @attribute directive for the Authorize attribute, like this: `@attribute [Authorize]` When an unauthenticated user tries to access the Fetchdata page, the AuthorizeRouteView.NotAuthorized delegate property is executed, and the RedirectToLogin component is rendered with its parameter attribute set to the current url.

The following addition is to add a login and logout buttons to your App...

1. Create a component named LoginDisplay.razor in the Shared folder, and add the following code into it:

```
     <AuthorizeView>
      <Authorized>
        <a href="Identity/Account/Manage">Hello, 
        @context.User.Identity.Name!</a>
        <form method="post" action="Identity/Account/LogOut">
            <button type="submit" class="nav-link btn btn-link">Log 
        out</button>
        </form>
      </Authorized>
         <NotAuthorized>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Register">Register</a>
            <a href="Identity/Account/Login">Log in</a>
         </NotAuthorized>
      </AuthorizeView>
```

In the MainLayout component add the LoginDisplay element as follows:

```
<div class="top-row px-4 auth">
    <LoginDisplay />
    <a href="https://learn.microsoft.com/aspnet/" 
         target="_blank">About</a>
</div>
```

Run your app and test the login and logout button...

Comment: Thank you for the big explanation of Login!
My question is how to merge a login form into my existing razor file - so I want to use the input fields and the login logic within the whole application layout design (without redirecting to a custom login page). Is this possible or do I have to do the redirect? Thx!

Comment: No, this is not possible. The code here does the complete handling of authentication and authorization, and that is the way to go using the Identity UI.

Comment: I don't think using the default UI is a good idea. You want to have control over what gets displayed to the user. Especially the user profile page! The default UI is added when calling services.AddDefaultIdentity on startup instead of services.AddIdentity. It's just a default UI. If we can get the source code of that default UI, then we can implement it in other ways. I'm still looking into this. Unfortunately, we can't get this from scaffolding; nor can we use Razor authentication pages.

Comment: I still haven't found anything. I created this thread to ask 
MS for source code scaffolding https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/23417